# unity2d, trajectory prediction shaking

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a mobile game that uses trajectory to find out the next path from my player. When the player is silent the trajectory works very well, but when the player is moving the trajectory sometimes moves on its own even though it returns to its proper position later, but this is very disturbing.
Here's the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static PlayerMovement Instance;

    Rigidbody2D rb;

    Vector3 startPos;
    Vector3 endPos;
    [HideInInspector] public Vector3 initPos;

    [HideInInspector] public Vector3 direction;
    public static Vector3 anotherSpeed;  // Only for trajectory
    float speedMultiplier = 1.5f;

    public GameObject trajectoryDot;
    GameObject[] trajectoryDots;
    public int numbersOfTrajectory;
    float trajectoryDotsDistance = 0.001f;

    public static float energy = 100f;
    public Slider energyBar;

    float slowDownFactor = 0.3f;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (!Instance)
            Instance = this;

        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        trajectoryDots = new GameObject[numbersOfTrajectory];
    }

    void Update()
    {
        anotherSpeed = direction;

        if (!Pause.isPaused)
        {
            // Get Start Position
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {

                // Instansiate The Trajectory
                for (int i = 0; i < numbersOfTrajectory; i++)
                {
                    trajectoryDots[i] = Instantiate(trajectoryDot,gameObject.transform.position, gameObject.transform.rotation);
                }
            }

            // Get Position When Dragging
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            {
                EnableSlowMotion();

                // Get Drag Position
                endPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) + new Vector3(0, 0, 10);

                startPos = gameObject.transform.position;

                // Get The Speed

                direction = endPos - startPos;
                direction = direction.normalized;
                direction = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, direction, 500 * Time.deltaTime);
                direction = direction * 18;

                // Update The Trajectory Position
                for (int i = 0; i < numbersOfTrajectory; i++)
                {
                    trajectoryDots[i].transform.position = calculatePosition(i * trajectoryDotsDistance);
                }
            }

            // Get Position When Realeasing
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
            {

                DisableSlowMotion();

                // enable Gravity
                rb.gravityScale = 1f;

                // Move The Player
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(direction.x * speedMultiplier, direction.y * speedMultiplier);


                // Destroy The Trajectory When Player Release
                for (int i = 0; i < numbersOfTrajectory; i++)
                {
                    Destroy(trajectoryDots[i]);
                }
            }

        }

        CameraZoom();
        ControlsChecker();
    }


    // Calculate The Trajectory Prediction 
    Vector2 calculatePosition(float elapsedTime)
    {
        return new Vector2(startPos.x, startPos.y) +
               new Vector2(anotherSpeed.x * speedMultiplier, anotherSpeed.y * speedMultiplier) * elapsedTime +
                0.5f * Physics2D.gravity * elapsedTime * elapsedTime;
    }



    // Check Controls Is pull or push 
    void ControlsChecker()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Controls") == 1)
        {
            direction = direction;
            anotherSpeed = anotherSpeed;
        }
        else
        {
            direction = -direction;
            anotherSpeed = -anotherSpeed;
        }
    }


    void EnableSlowMotion()
    {
        Time.timeScale = slowDownFactor;
        Time.fixedDeltaTime = 0.02f * Time.timeScale;
    }

    void DisableSlowMotion()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        Time.fixedDeltaTime = 0.02F;
    }
}


void CameraZoom()
{
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            vcam.m_Lens.OrthographicSize += 0.1f;
            if (vcam.m_Lens.OrthographicSize >= maxZoom)
            {
                vcam.m_Lens.OrthographicSize = maxZoom;
            }
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            zoomIn = true;
        }

        if (zoomIn)
        {
            vcam.m_Lens.OrthographicSize -= 0.2f;
            if (vcam.m_Lens.OrthographicSize <= minZoom)
            {
                vcam.m_Lens.OrthographicSize = minZoom;
                zoomIn = false;
            }
        }
}
```

so I get the player's movement direction from the calculation based on the point where I touch and the point when I release touch (dragging). Did I make a mistake in the code that caused my trajectory to vibrate often? I really need help here, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried doing it in LateUpdate instead of Update? It often helps when trying to set some objects position relative to rigidbody

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering my question, I was able to overcome this problem, when I saw your answer I immediately remembered to play the update, I used fixedUpdate and it resolved my problem. I haven't tried lateUpdate though. But thanks to you, I remember to use another update because so far I only use updates in all my code.